# Is there a way of publishing Akka actors with Mina?

Tags: scala

I've been reading up about Akka and it really seems nice. Can you somehow set it up to work with Apache Mina or similar techs? I.e not only use it in conjunction with servlets.

Answer (score 2):

Hmmm, seems you already have a technical solution (Mina). 
May I ask what is the problem you're trying to solve?

RemoteActors are using Netty, it's basically only the JAX-RS (Jersey) and Comet (Atmosphere) integration that runs over servlets.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I must have missed how things with RemoteActors are working. I guess it's not too big of a problem to add your own serializer for Netty either? Been thinking of adding BlazeDS stuff (AMF).

Comment: I have no experience in using BlazeDS, but I assume you could always call Akka from your BlazeDS component. Would that do what you're asking for?

Comment: I'm looking at http://github.com/jboner/akka/blob/master/akka-core/src/main/scala/remote/RemoteProtocolBuilder.scala now. Is there no way for a user to add a custom serializer without editing the core?

Comment: Currently not, but do you need to? RemoteClient is for Akka-actor->Akka-actor communication.

Comment: Ah, I see. Stuff looks similar at http://github.com/jboner/akka/tree/master/akka-core/src/main/scala/serialization/ too tho. Flash clients have a native way to serialize stuff called AMF. I'm investigating how easy it would be to use Akka with AMF and a flash/flex client.

Comment: That'd be a really cool experiment! 
You can use the Akka JAX-RS support, have a look at the samples for more info. Then you can probably take some inspiration from this: http://docs.codehaus.org/display/ENUNCIATE/AMF+and+REST

And then you have flash -> Akka over AMF

Comment: Thanks for the link, I've been looking for something like that but not been finding it. Can JAX-RS stuff be used with comet stuff?

Comment: Sure can! :-) You can also use clustering and/or HTTP Auth security for the JAX-RS stuff (so you can have fault-tolerance and/or secured services)